# TableView not displaying array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

I have an app which searches for services after it loads. Unfortunately, I cannot get my table to display my Mutable Array. It is supposed to have a cell (according to `NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[self.services count]);`)! Everything seems correct, other than the cell not being there. I have the same Reuse ID and the array has an object. A snippet of code is available below:

The Add to Array Code (its the first at the top of the code!):

```
- (void)addService:(NSNetService *)service moreComing:(BOOL)more {
NSLog(@"%@", service.name);

[self.services addObject:service];

NSLog(@"IT WORKED! MY TIME MACHINE WORKED!");
if(!more) {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
[self.tableView reloadData];
NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[self.services count]);
NSString * result = [[self.services valueForKey:@"name"] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSLog(result);
```

}

The Cell code:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
           [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = [[_services objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]name];
    NSLog([[_services objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] name]);
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
```

I have also set the delegate/data source in the code as well as through IB:

```
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.delegate = self;
```

Here is the log from a run that is supposed to work:

```
2013-11-06 17:35:37.808 TrolioDemo[5846:60b] Adding service from the delegate
2013-11-06 17:35:37.811 TrolioDemo[5846:60b] Keaton’s MacBook Pro
```

Thats supposed to be the text of the cell.

```
2013-11-06 17:35:37.812 TrolioDemo[5846:60b] IT WORKED! MY TIME MACHINE WORKED!
2013-11-06 17:35:37.817 TrolioDemo[5846:60b] 1
```

Thats the count of the self.services array

```
2013-11-06 17:35:37.818 TrolioDemo[5846:60b] Keaton’s MacBook Pro
```

Comment: Did you link correctly your delegate and data source to your UIViewController ?

Comment: Yes, both programmatically and thru the storyboard.

Comment: Did you set the cell identifier for your UICellView in your storyboard ?

Comment: And what about those delegates methods ?
-numberOfSectionsInTableView
-numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: @Defoncesko those check out. The section returns 1. I used NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[self.services count]); and it spits out 1 on the -numberOfRowsInSection

Comment: The cells work if the array is defined before viewDidload

Comment: but its a static array

Comment: @Defoncesko yeah. gave up

Answer (score 0):

Change it to dynamic array through the storyboard